Design patterns specific to scientific publications
One area that I think the scientific field is probably ahead of the rest of the IT industry is the maturity in data visualization and presentation of data because of the specialization of science communication.
However, I am wondering if there are any literature or research in the area of design patterns that are specific to science publications, especially that of journal articles in the print or digital format.
I am aware of some UX design relevant for websites like Wolfram Alpha and applications like Jupyter Notebook that can be used for scientific calculations and content display, and hoping to find examples of more from the community.
UPDATE: There are also individuals and small groups of the scientific community interested in applying UX design concepts and techniques like ScienceUX and UXLS

I'm not exactly sure what you're looking for with this question. Publications have their own guidelines, both for the paper itself and any associated figures. Researchers have investigated effective dataviz for scientific papers, and identified pitfalls and recommendations. Is that what you're looking for?

@KitGrose there is a community on Reddit looking at the user experience of science related applications and scientific publications: https://www.reddit.com/r/ScienceUX/ so I am curious as to whether the scientific community might take a more evidence-based approach to design. I know that data visualization is a strong aspect of science, but user interface design not so much.
